# object-defined error when using .Find to merge tables in VBA

Tags: excel, find, match, vba

I'm trying to write my first macro from scratch. I have a set of 16 tables on Sheet2, with the columns in the pattern: ID list, blank, value1, value2, value3, value4, blank, next ID list, blank, value1 etc...

The IDs in each table are unique but not the same each time, so I am trying to write a macro to match the ID to a complete list of IDs which are found on Sheet1. If there is a match, I want to copy over the four value columns into the right place on Sheet1. Otherwise just put in some zeroes.

If you can't tell already, I'm new to this and have no idea what I'm doing! I'm getting
"application-defined or object-defined error" on the line where I try to use .Find, I would really appreciate it if somebody could point out where I'm going wrong?

```
Sub Macro1()

Dim i As Integer
Dim y As Integer
Dim index As Long
Dim UniverseCount As Integer
Dim ID As String
Dim Position As Range


'Count total number of IDs    
Sheets("Sheet1").Select
Range("A2").Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
UniverseCount = Selection.Rows.Count


'Search loop
For y = 0 To 16
For i = 0 To UniverseCount


'Pick ID to look for
Sheets("Sheet1").Select
Range("A2").Offset(i, 0).Select
ID = Selection.Value

With Sheet2
Set Position = .Columns(7 * y).Find(What:=ID, After:=.Cells(1, 1), LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)

    If Not Position Is Nothing Then
    Position.Offset(0, 2).Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlRight)).Select
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A2").Offset(i, 2 + 4 * y).Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste

    Else
    Sheets("Sheet1").Select
    Range("A2").Offset(i, 2 + 4 * y).Select
    Set Range(Selection, Selection.Offset(0, 4)).Value = 0

    End If
End With

Next i
Next y

End Sub
```

Comment: I reckon this would be much easier with ADO. You could, for example, open each table range as a table with a LEFT JOIN to the main table on sheet1. How exactly to set up your queries will depend on what is going in and what you want back out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your key issue is that this `Find` line on Sheet2 is inconsistent

```
Set Position = .Columns(7 * y).Find(What:=ID, After:=.Cells(1, 1), LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)
```

The code is iterating from 0 to 16 (which presumably should be 1 to 16) but your disconnect is the column you are searching for in `.Columns(7 * y)` is *variable* ie, 0, 7, 14 **but** you are attempting to start the search in `A1` each time with `After:=.Cells(1, 1)`. Hence the error as the code can't search column G (column 7), P (column 14) etc starting in A1

If you try
`Set Position = .Columns(7 * y).Find(What:=ID, After:=.Cells(1, 7 * y), LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)`
then your search will be internally consistent on the same column

Next step is to work on remove the `Select` statements for more efficient code.:)

**Part 2)**
As you have found `Postion` without activating the sheet you either need to

1) Activate Position
2) Avoid `Select` altogether

Lets go with (2)

Try replacing

```
Position.Offset(0, 2).Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlRight)).Select
Selection.Copy
Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A2").Offset(i, 2 + 4 * y).Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
```

with

`Range(Position.Offset(0, 2), Position.Offset(0, 2).End(xlToRight)).Copy Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A2").Offset(i, 2 + 4 * y)`

Comment: Thanks so much! This has helped me a lot. However, now that the Find is working I have met another problem.... I was expecting .Find to return a Range object? So that I could use Position.Offset(0,2).Select - but instead it seems to return the value of the cell. i.e after Set Position = .Find , Position = ID! Is it not possible to have Position = the range where the ID is found?

Comment: That worked, brilliant!! I will work on removing those selects in future :)